# Close Aura Workspace Tab & Opening Another Throws processReplaceSubtabPage Exception

Tags: lightning-aura-components, workspaceapi

I have a Lightning record-page that is displayed to users, which contains an Aura component wrapping some Lightning Web Components.

**When this operation runs, it works but I am somewhat randomly getting an exception message: (Grey Report to Salesforce)**

> [LCE: workspaceManager#processReplaceSubtabPage() - Failed to process
> request: jobLibrary - Job: processReplaceSubtabPage, Stage: tasks, Job
> failed. An error occurred while processing. LCE:
> workspaceManager#replaceTab() - Unable to replace tab. Subtab not
> found: ctab0_1]
> eval()@https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/components/navex/workspaceManager.js:3501:31
> Object.promise()@https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/components/navex/workspaceManager.js:3104:16
> Object.replaceTab()@https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/components/navex/workspaceManager.js:3493:23

*What is happening when this issue appears*:

Once the user' completes their work on the Lightning page containing the Aura component I send an event to "Close" the current tab - and "Launch" another Aura component tab.

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
workspaceAPI
      .getEnclosingTabId()
      .then(function (tabId) {
            var pageReference = {
              pageReference: {
                type: "standard__component",
                attributes: {
                  componentName: "c__myComponent" // c__<comp Name>
                },
                state: {
                  uid: "1",
                  // ...
                }
              },
              focus: true
            };

          workspaceAPI
            .openSubtab(pageReference)
            .then(function (response) {
              helper.closeWorkspaceTab(component);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
})
```

And in the Aura Component tab that opens (in the markup I use a "pageReference" handler to read the state):

```
  <aura:handler
    name="init"
    value="{!this}"
    action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"
  />
  <aura:handler
    name="change"
    value="{!v.pageReference}"
    action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"
  />
```

And in the Controller:

```
  onPageReferenceChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    // pull the current tab first
    workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function (tabId) {
      workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
        tabId: tabId,
        label: "Follow-up Task"
      });
      workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
        tabId: tabId,
        icon: "action:new_task",
        iconAlt: "Follow-Up Task"
      });
    });
  });
```